# Asp.net Core MVC Roles and Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authorization

For a school project I am remaking the Top2000 website (dutch website with the top 2000 most liked songs per year). Now I have a problem with the roles and the authorization.

I want to add an admin role and give only user with that role access to the privacy page.
This is what I got so far:
**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            
            services.AddDbContext<db_a74225_top2000Context>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
namespace Top2000.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of **dbo.AspNetUserRoles**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHqpe.png)

[Screenshot of **dbo.AspNetUsers**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Va5Y.png)

[Screenshot of **dbo.AspNetRoles**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV1H5.png)

I expect to get to the privacy page but when I login I still get Access Denied.

[Screenshot of Access denied page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aU6L.png)

Comment: Do you have `app.UseAuthentication` & `app.UseAuthorization()` in `Startup:Configure` method?

Comment: Yes I have in that order. I will append it to my question.

Comment: Hi @Samball,any update about this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the screenshot of your database, you may not have successfully created a role, you can create a user with a role like the following method `CreateRolesandUsers`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    public HomeController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    public async Task CreateRolesandUsers()
    {

        bool x = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
        if (!x)
        {
            var role = new IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Admin";
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
        }
        var user = new IdentityUser();
        user.UserName = "123@123.com";
        user.Email = "123@123.com";
        string password = "Defaultpassword01!";

        IdentityResult chkUser = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

        if (chkUser.Succeeded)
        {
            var result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
        }
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Your DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Then in your startup change your code

```
 services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

to

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultUI()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

When you access this method to successfully create a role, you can log in to the user and then access Privacy.

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested but when I look in my database the Admin role is not created. Do I have to call the CreateRolesandUsers() method and where?

Comment: You can access the method directly in the url

Comment: Do I specifically need to go to that url? So localhost/home/CreateRolesandUsers? Because I tried that but than I get an threading error. Multiple threads using the same instance of DbContext.

Comment: Why do you have two dbcontexts using the same connection string in your project.

Comment: What is your `db_a74225_top2000Context`?Are there two databases in your project? Which one of your dbcontexts inherits from `IdentityDbContext`?

Comment: I made a mistake. I have changed .AddEntityFrameworkStores<db_a74225_top2000Context>() to the correct Context but now I get the error: 'Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityRole' because this type is not included in the model for the context.' Also I removed the ApplicationContext. `db_a74225_top2000Context` is from my database.

Comment: Your dbcontext should like following `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext`,and in your startup :`services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultUI()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();`

Comment: I have `public partial class db_a74225_top2000Context : DbContext` not IdentityDbContext

Comment: What is your `ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: I don't know what you mean with that but I use `db_a74225_top2000Context` as my ApplicationDbContext if that is what you mean.

Comment: Did you check Enable authentication when you created the project? Then there should be ApplicationDbContext in your project. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C91Dm.png).Then you will not need to create an additional DbContext.If som,you need to delete the code `services.AddDbContext<db_a74225_top2000Context>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`,and do the change in startup like my answer.

Comment: I have that but now I get the error: 'The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined.'

Comment: In fact, you only need to create a brand new project with authentication, then follow the steps in my answer, and then migrate the database.it will work well.